# django auth error

Tags: django

how to fix this

> Error: One or more models did not validate:
>   auth.permission: 'content_type' has a relation with model class 'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType', which has either not been installed or is abstract.

Comment: Write more details, i.e. model code with field `content_type`

Comment: i have 'django.contrib.sessions' and 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' is my settings.py with 0 errors. uncommenting **'django.contrib.auth'** in _INSTALLED_APPS_ produces the above error

Comment: its look like you don't have app needed by django.contrib.autho in INSTALLED_APPS. Check example codes using dajngo.contrib.auth for apps in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: worked like a charm, i was following django book to the dot which doesnt mention the additional app. where as [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) describes 'django.contrib.contenttypes' as an additional app for instllation. thank you so much!!